# What is the encoding of an .eml file from IIS's SMTP server?

Tags: iis, encoding, smtp, transfer-encoding

I need to write a program that read the `.eml` files from IIS's mail drop box, but I can't find a definitive source that tells me the encoding of the `.eml` files. Is there a specification somewhere that tells me the encoding of the files, or do I just have to guess/assume one?

Comment: I think I found my answer at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME: "The basic Internet e-mail transmission protocol, SMTP, supports only 7-bit ASCII characters... "

Comment: Why don't you add an answer? You won't be able to get rep points but that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: I hesitate to add it an an answer because I'm not sure if I'm correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME: "The basic Internet e-mail transmission protocol, SMTP, supports only 7-bit ASCII characters... "

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the Content-Transfer-Encoding header. This value will tell you how the email is encoded. The most common are 7-Bit (no encoding), Quoted-Printable (where you see a lot of =HEX pairs), and base64 (which is base 64 encoding).

Based upon that header value, you decode the following body part using the specified routine.

Comment: Thanks Dave. The problem is reading the header itself. Can I assume that the headers are ACII characters?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the name "Quoted-Printable." I don't think I'd find it in a reasonable amount of time with your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's too late to answer but eml file format nothing but a plaintext MIME (rfc822) file format for storing emails.